# Force refresh doesn't work for Head JS

Tags: javascript, browser-cache, head.js

When scripts are loaded via [Head JS](http://headjs.com/) I am unable to force the content to refresh using the Ctrl+F5 (or equivalent) keyboard shortcut.

The scripts cache correctly and the browser obeys the cache directives sent from the server (I'm using IIS 7.5). But unlike scripts tags included directly in the markup, I can't override the cache and force a refresh of the scripts loaded via Head JS.

I'm assuming this is a consequence of the way the scripts are loaded dynamically. I can live with this behaviour because forcing the refresh is only convenient during development, and I know of other ways I can force the content to be retrieved from the server.

I just wondered if anyone could explain why this is the case...

#### Update

This was never a problem for us in Live, because the cache directives for our static content were set appropriately. It was only ever a problem in Development and QA, The options left available to me were...

- Configure all Dev and QA browsers to never cache content.
- Configure the static content cache directives differently for Dev and QA environments - essentially setting MaxAge to something so small the content would always be expired. Only setting the correct MaxAge value in Live.

I went with the second option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic script loading is not a part of the page loading proper. When you force refresh, the browser reloads the page and all resources referenced in its HTML and in referenced CSS files, but the scripts you load with `head.js` are not referenced in the page content and the browser has no way to figure out that `head.js` is going to create references to additional resources. At the point where these references are created, the browser is no longer refreshing the page and thus normal cache rules apply.

You can force reload of your scripts by appending unique query strings to their URLs (e.g. `jquery.js?random=437593486394`), but this will disable caching for all loads of your page, not just when you force refresh.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It does make sense that the browser can only determine the static references, not ones made at runtime. I was wrongly assuming that the browser would force the refresh at the time the request was actually made, and since all requests happen at runtime it would also include these dynamic requests made by head.js. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This is also a problem with require.js. Hopefully one of these work arounds will also apply to Head.Js

- If using Chrome, open the developer tools panel on the Network tab, right click and choose 'Clear Browser Cache'
- Do a bit of 'Cache-busting' by appending a datetime stamp to the query string for js resources
- If your using IIS (which it looks like you are). Go to the HTTP Response Headers panel of your website, click Set Common Headers and set Expire Web content to immediately.

The latter is my preferred option for my development machine

[image: IIS HTTP Response Headers Panel]

Comment: Thanks for those options. Very helpful. I would add another one for users of IE9+. Under Developer Tools -> Cache menu, there is an option to "Always refresh from Server". This seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say its a question of dynamic or not dynamic, when you inject a script it still causes the browser to make a HTTP request and apply whatever caching logic it applies.

Like mentioned above if you don't want scripts to be cached ..dynamic or static, it doesn't matter, you will usually have to append a timestamp in the form of a query string to it.

If you just want to see if you changes are working, do a force refresh in your browser ...usually CTRL+F5

Comment: That's my point, the Ctrl+F5 doesn't work when the scripts are loaded dynamically. When they are statically referenced the browser seems able to work out which scripts it needs to retrieve from the server. However when they are not statically referenced, it can't. It must then default to the cache instructions it already has for each script. Waiting for the cached file to expire or manually clearing the cache are the only options left.

Comment: Strange, i never had a problem to get my browser to refresh things. The only problems i usually encounter is that it's IIS or the company proxy that is caching the content, not the browser. Have you verified this behavior by tracing your browser requests (firebug, fiddler..) ?